# Wrong logic in approximating e^1 :(

Tags: c++

I've written code using class object to calculate the value of e^1 by approximation using the summation of series given below, but seems like i can't get the logic to work properly.I tried running it to 5 terms for approximation but my answer was 1.2 only where it should be around 2.7038...

e^1 is given by the series 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class factorial
{
public:
double loopfactorial ( double y)
    {

        double value;
    for (int a=0; a<=y; a++)
        {
            value=1;

            value = value*a;
        }
        return value;
    }
};


int main()
{
factorial calcu;
int x;
double sum;
cout<<"Enter the number of terms to approximate exponent:"<<endl;
cin>>x;

for (int y=1; y<=x-1; y++)
{
int n = calcu.loopfactorial(y);

sum=1.0;
sum = sum + 1/n;
}

cout<<"The value of e is "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `sum=1.0;` inside the loop body?

Comment: @KerrekSB and in the calculate factorial as well

Comment: hmmm, because there is a 1 in the exponent series?

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski: That's actually required, but storing the result in an `int` is going to make for the next question.

Comment: @KerrekSB are you referring to int n? I thought since n is just a factorial of some numbers.

Comment: Why is `factorial` a class? Nothing would be lost my making `loopfactorial` a standalone function and removing the `calcu` object.

Comment: @KerrekSB but not in the loop, this will result in the return value equal to floor(y)

Comment: Why are you calculating the next item when you know the previous one? Why start from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

For reference and the benefit of future readers, here's the "correct" code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    unsigned int terms;
    if (!(std::cout << "Number of terms: " && std::cin >> terms))
    {
        std::cout << "Error, I did not understand you.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    double e = terms > 0 ? 1.0 : 0.0, term = 1.0;
    for (unsigned int n = 1; n < terms; ++n)
    {
        term /= n;
        e += term;    // this is "e += 1/n!"
    }

    std::cout << "e is approximately " << e << "\n";
}
```

(The code can be trivially extended to compute *e*<sup>*x*</sup> for any *x*.)

Comment: `double e = terms > 0 ? 1.0 : 0.0, term = 1.0;`  Splitting that into two statements improves its readability quite a bit :)

Comment: I tend to view the ternary operator as a very-rarely-necessary evil. In this case, it's only necessary due to the way the `for` loop is constructed. If you replace `n < terms` with `n <= terms` and put `term /= n` *after* `e += term`, then you could just initialize `e` to `0.0`, and the ternary operator goes away. The only downside is that you do one unnecessary `term /= n` calculation on the last iteration. In my mind that's a small price to pay to get rid of the ternary operator ugliness.

Comment: More likely, though, I'd have this code in a function, and just do a preemptive `if (terms < 1) return 0.0;` at the top of the function. Then you could leave the loop as you have it here (thus avoiding the extra division on the last iteration), and just initialize `e` to `1.0`. Either way, the ternary operator can be dispensed with, which IMO significantly improves readability.

Comment: @MikeHolt: Sure, any variation on the theme is possible. Pick whatever you like best.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the variable initializations out of the loops - you're resetting them over and over.

Side note: it's rather pointless to put `loopfactorial` in a class.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your initial values outside the loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class factorial
{
public:
double loopfactorial ( double y)
    {

        double value;
        // MOVED INITIAL VALUE HERE
        value=1;
    for (int a=1; a<=y; a++)
        {
            value = value*a;
        }
        return value;
    }
};


int main()
{
factorial calcu;
int x;
double sum;
cout<<"Enter the number of terms to approximate exponent:"<<endl;
cin>>x;

// MOVED INITIAL VALUE HERE
sum=1.0;
for (int y=1; y<=x-1; y++)
{
int n = calcu.loopfactorial(y);

sum = sum + 1/n;
}

cout<<"The value of e is "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Why is the answer always 1?" :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB Don't you mean "Why is the answer always 0?". Look at the loop: `for (int a=0; ...)`

Comment: @MikeHolt: Nicely spotted. I was referring to `sum = sum + 0`, but in fact we have `sum = sum + 0/0`. Wonderful.

Comment: @KerrekSB I was only referring to the code inside `loopfactorial`. I didn't even notice the `sum = sum + 1/n`. So it's actually more like "Why is the answer always Error: Divide by 0?" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found three problems with your code, both are similar to each other
1. in `loopfactorial()`, `value=1` should be defined before the loop body
2. in `main()`, `sum=1.0` should be defined before the loop body
3. in `loopfactorial()`, loop variable `a` should have been initialized with either 1 or 2 instead of 0.

Comment: thanks! it's been only 7 weeks since i started C++ with no prior background, so some concepts are pretty much vague to me.

Comment: @user3499156 cool, c++ is the most basic step before learning any other programming language. Wish you good luck, keep asking when you are stuck and don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you